# Received time of file in Linux

Tags: linux, ftp, lftp

I'm sending a file from one server to another via `lftp`.

Suppose S1 and S2 is two server.

A file **file1** is created at S1 at  `Mar 27 19:41`. `ls -ltrh` shows it. 
I sent the file  to S2 at `Mar 28 20:00` from S1. I want to know this time from S2. That means the received time of that **file1** in S2. But it showing creating time in S1 and that is  `Mar 27 19:41`. How to do it?

Comment: Check the last modified time?

Comment: Use `rsync` for file transfers. Supports ftp, ssh, etc. If you don't use the `-t` and `-a` switch , it shouldn't preserve the modification times.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` does not show creation time; that's the *modification* time. Almost all file transfer tools adjust it after copying the file, since the last-modification time of the file's contents in general is much more useful than the birth date of just this specific instance of that file.

Currently there is no way to see the *actual* creation time of a file in Linux without resorting to filesystem management tools such as `debugfs`. On some BSDs, however, it already has its own entry in `stat`.